# how to fix syntax error while if...else statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
import webbrowser
Character_Name = "Random"
Character_Age = "14"

input("Name of the person you want the ID of.")
print("Here's The Information That I Have: Name:" + Character_Name + ", Age:" + Character_Age + ", Available socialmedia accounts: (insta) www.instagram.com/asenpai369")

a = input("Should i open the link in your web browser?")

if a : "Yes"
webbrowser.open("www.instagram.com/idksoumyadeep")

else:
print("okay, if its a mistype then please type it again")
```

and the error

```
        else:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

please help thanks in advance :))

Comment: At the very least, you have indentation errors. I don't know what you expect `if a : "Yes"` to mean. (Are you just mistaking `:` for `==`?)

Comment: You also never assign the result of the first `input` to `Character_Name`, which I assume is your intent.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
if a == "Yes": webbrowser.open("www.instagram.com/idksoumyadeep")
else: print("okay, if its a mistype then please type it again")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use indentation after the `if` and `else`:

```py
import webbrowser
Character_Name = "Random"
Character_Age = "14"

input("Name of the person you want the ID of.")
print("Here's The Information That I Have: Name:" + Character_Name + ", Age:" + Character_Age + ", Available socialmedia accounts: (insta) www.instagram.com/asenpai369")

a = input("Should i open the link in your web browser?")

if a == "Yes":
    webbrowser.open("www.instagram.com/idksoumyadeep")

else:
    print("okay, if its a mistype then please type it again")
```